# Qt/C++ : get Ui QLineEdit text from another class

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simple test to use an UI object made with "Qt Design" but I'm pretty new to Qt and C++.
I've got a quite simple Ui : 3 `LineEdit`s and 1 `PushButton` :
[`IMAGE : the UI window`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGsrl.png)

I've a Client Class which is supposed to control Ui. It connects the `QPushButton` and it should get the content from `QLineEdit`.
But the result in `QDebug` is always the same when I push the Button, even when I change `QlineEdit` field: **"Client connected :  "" : 0 "**

Moreover, if I use *`on_pushButton_clicked`* made with QtDesign, it will display the real values of `QlineEdit`s.

Why the `QString`s are always the same ? Am I passing a copy of the initial object ? How to solve that ?

Is it the good way to make a `ViewController` ? Else, what is the good way?

**Client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "logwindow.h"

Client::Client()
{
    LogWindow* w1 = new LogWindow();
    MainWindow* w2 = new MainWindow();

    _stack = new QStackedWidget();
    _stack->addWidget(w1);
     connect(w1->getButton(),SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(connexion()));

    _stack->addWidget(w2);
    _stack->show();
}

//When the button is Pushed, gets the content from QlineEdits and prints them
void Client::connexion()
{
    QString ip=(LogWindow (_stack->currentWidget())).getIP();
    int port=((LogWindow (_stack->currentWidget())).getPort()).toInt();

    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost(ip, port);

    _stack->setCurrentIndex((_stack->currentIndex()+1)%_stack->count());
    qDebug() <<"Client connected : " << ip << ":"<<port;
}
```

And a class made automatically by Qt :

**LogWindow.cpp**

```
#include "logwindow.h"
#include "ui_logwindow.h"



LogWindow::LogWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::LogWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

LogWindow::~LogWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


QPushButton* LogWindow::getButton()
{
    return ui->pushButton;
}

QString LogWindow::getIP()
{
    //LineEdit named "IP_text"
    return ui->IP_text->text();
}

QString LogWindow::getPort()
{
    //LineEdit named "Port_text"
    return ui->Port_text->text();
}
```

**LogWindow.h**

```
namespace Ui {
class LogWindow;
}

class LogWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LogWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~LogWindow();
    QPushButton* getButton();
    QString getIP();
    QString getPort();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::LogWindow *ui;
};
```

Comment: In `Client::connexion` you are creating a new instance of `LogWindow`. Make `LogWindow* w1` a member variable of your `Client` class, if you want to access it in other `Client`'s member functions as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't know how I missed that, I wasn't using w1 to get IP....
And about programming, is it a good thing to manage interface like I am doiing?

Comment: There is not much to complain about, except that `_stack ` is a widget without a parent, so you must make sure you destroy it when you don't need it anymore (*for example call `delete _stack;` in the destructor*). Most beginners would have tried to make the `ui` variable public to get the data from `IP_text`, but you did correctly, by making the `LogWindow::getIP` function.

Comment: If you don't want to expose `ui->pushButton` outside of your class, you can make a signal for your `LogWindow` class, and connect the `clicked` signal of `ui->pushButton` to that signal. You can connect signals to signals, it doesn't have to be a slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Thuga solved it :*

> In Client::connexion you are creating a new instance of LogWindow.
>   Make LogWindow* w1 a member variable of your Client class, if you want
>   to access it in other Client's member functions as well.
>
> There is not much to complain about, except that _stack is a widget
>   without a parent, so you must make sure you destroy it when you don't
>   need it anymore (for example call delete _stack; in the destructor).
>   Most beginners would have tried to make the ui variable public to get
>   the data from IP_text, but you did correctly, by making the
>   LogWindow::getIP function.
>
> If you don't want to expose ui->pushButton outside of your class, you
>   can make a signal for your LogWindow class, and connect the clicked
>   signal of ui->pushButton to that signal. You can connect signals to
>   signals, it doesn't have to be a slot.